# kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host Connection closed by 43.134.20.100 port 6000

Tags: linux, ssh

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % ssh -oPort=6000 johnBS@43.134.20.100 -vvv
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 43.134.20.100 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/wangbaohua/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/wangbaohua/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 43.134.20.100 [43.134.20.100] port 6000.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 43.134.20.100 port 6000: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 43.134.20.100 port 6000: Connection refused
```

I have a linuxPC in the home LAN network, I use frp Intranet penetration, in my use of LAN ssh link is OK, but the use of the Internet there is no way to access, log as above, do you know what the problem is, I established an issue in frp github, There was feedback that it was because of key authentication issues

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error message in your title is different from the error message in your ssh debug output. What actual problem are you having? Why do you think you should be able to connect to port 6000 with ssh?